# MySQL WHERE something = $something and $something = every value by default

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to do a filter for my online shop.
I have the following query

```
$column = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT brand FROM shields WHERE
brand=".$brand." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$offset. "," . $itemsPerPage);
```

I want `$brand` to be equal to `1`, `2` and `3` by default to show every item on my shop, and when I filter then it would change `$brand` to `1`, `2` or `3` with this code

```
$brand = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'brand', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

Comment: What about just `brand between 1 and 3`?

Comment: Write a stored proc that conditionally appends the where clause.

Comment: How do I use brand between 1 and 3? I can't put $brand = 1-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make like this :

```
if(isset($_POST["brand"])){
  $brand = $_POST["brand"]; // filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'brand', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
  $filterByBrand = "and brand =".$brand;
}
else{
  $brand = "1,2,3";
  $filterByBrand = "and brand in(".$brand.")";
}


$column = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT brand FROM shields WHERE 1=1 
".$filterByBrand." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$offset. "," . $itemsPerPage);
```

Comment: Your code worked, only I used filter_input to get $brand. Why did you use $_POST, is it better in some way or something?

Comment: I am happy to help.
I don't have special reason, you can use filter_input of course.